# zsh-like autocompletion in ipython

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython, zsh, zsh-completion

One thing I like about zsh autocompletion is how it handles situation when more than 1 item matches the pattern. Say I have folders:

```
./
  abc/
  bbc/
  bcd/
```

In zsh, when I type `b` and `<TAB>`, I can see all the suggestions starting with `b` (same as in ipython).

But, when I type `<TAB>` once more in zsh, the autocompleter starts to shift between currently matching suggestions (in the example above `bbc` and `bcd`) and I can accept a suggestion by pressing `<ENTER>`. On the other hand, in ipython I have to type the next letter (`b` or `c`) to choose the correct completion.

I would like to have zsh-like completion in ipython -- did anyone manage to get that?

Comment: Have you tried to send a lovely message to iPython devs?

Comment: Not yet, but it seems ipython devs read the SO ipython tag. Besides, I would not be surprised if someone implemented/set this kind of autocompletion in a form of library and not inside ipython code.

Comment: The latest `ipython` (5.+) has a new tab completer.  It shows a window of suggestions, which you can scroll through.  Or you can add some text and <tab> again.  In someways I prefer the old style, but I'm getting used to the new.

Comment: In the latest repeated tabs steps through the list

Comment: The latest Ipython uses `prompt_toolkit` instead of `readline`.  That package mentions `fish` shell as the model for its completions.

Comment: Ok, the newest autocompletion mechanism satisfy my needs. Thanks for pointing it out and sorry I didn't update ipython before I asked.